# Angle between two curves on curved space

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, parametrization

Today I did an exercise where I found the angle between two curves $\mathbf{x}(\lambda_1)$ and $\mathbf{x}(\lambda_2)$ on the surface of a unit sphere with line element $ds^2 = d \theta^2 + sin^2 \theta d \phi^2$. $\mathbf{x}(\lambda_1)$ and $\mathbf{x}(\lambda_2)$ are different functions. In my exercise they were $\theta = \theta_0 + \lambda_1$, $\phi = \phi_0 + \lambda_1$ and $\theta = \theta_0 - 2 \lambda_2$, $\phi = \phi_0 + \lambda_2. $ The method was something along these lines:

1. Parametrize a 'circle' $\mathbf{x}(\lambda_c)$ of very small radius $\epsilon$ centered about the point of intersection of the two curves $(\theta_0 , \phi_0)$. Since $\epsilon$ is small, assume $\sin \theta(\lambda_c) = \sin \theta_0$. This can be done using the line element. A 'circle' centered about $(\theta_0 , \phi_0)$ with radius $\epsilon$ should be given by the equation
   $$\epsilon^2 = (\theta - \theta_0)^2 + sin^2 \theta_0 (\phi - \phi_0)^2$$
   Then I parametrize this equation with parameter $\lambda_c$.
2. Find the values of $\lambda_c$ for which the two curves intersect the circle.
3. Find the arc length by integrating ds with limits given by the two values of $\lambda_c$ in the previous step
4. Divide the arc length by the radius $\epsilon$ to get the angle between the two curves

But I am not sure $s = r \theta$ holds in curved space. I'm assuming this works since the space is locally Euclidean. But then can't I just find the tangent vectors $d \mathbf{x}/d \lambda_1$ and $d \mathbf{x} / d \lambda_2$ and find the angle between these vectors like I would in a 2d Euclidean space to find the angle between the curves?

Comment: Your notation is confusing me here.  Are $\mathbf{x}(\lambda_1)$ and $\mathbf{x}(\lambda_2)$ supposed to be the same function evaluated at different parameter values?  Or should we think of them as two different functions $\mathbf{x}_1: \mathbb{R} \to S^2$ and $\mathbf{x}_2: \mathbb{R} \to S^2$?  And if so, which one is being used in step 1?

Comment: The line element (otherwise called the first fundamental form) allows you to compute not just lengths, but also angles. This is just a dot product on the tangent space.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Different functions. In my particular case it was $\theta = \theta_0 + \lambda_1$, $\phi = \phi_0 + \lambda_1$ and $\theta = \theta_0 - 2 \lambda_2$, $\phi = \phi_0 + \lambda_2$. Neither is being used in step 1. $\mathbf{x} (\lambda_1)$ and $\mathbf{x} (\lambda_2)$ are different curves, while $\mathbf{x} (\lambda_c)$ is a circle centered on their intersection point. I'll edit my question to make things clearer.

Comment: @TedShifrin I know since I already used the line element in the process of finding the angle. But that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: You cannot use the letter $\mathbf x$ for three different functions, as Michael already suggested. And no, $r=s\theta$ holds only in a flat space. Think about the length of the circle $\theta=\theta_0$ in your (spherical) space.

Comment: @TedShifrin Would it be more appropriate to use $\mathbf{x_1}(\lambda)$, $\mathbf{x_2}(\lambda)$, $\mathbf{x_c}(\lambda)$ instead of $\mathbf{x}(\lambda_1)$, $\mathbf{x}(\lambda_2)$, $\mathbf{x}(\lambda_c)$ ?

Comment: @TedShifrin But $\theta = \theta_0$ isn't a circle in my spherical space. It's a geodesic. By 'circle' I mean a circle as seen by an ant on the surface of the sphere, if you will. For such a 'circle', won't $s = r \theta$ be applicable for very small r?

Comment: No, $\theta=\theta_0$ is not a geodesic — that's $\phi=\phi_0$. (You are using the spherical coordinates used by physicists and everyone — it seems — except American mathematics students. And yes to your previous question.

Comment: Something seems off, $\lambda_c$..? Shouldn't each curve have different parameterizations? Of course when they intersect, each of them evaluated at their respective parameter agree but I can't believe other wise

Comment: @Buraian The line element in spherical coordinates is $ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2 d \theta^2 + r^2 \sin^2 \theta d \phi^2$. On the surface of a unit sphere, $dr = 0$ and $r=1$ which gives the line element I used. The curves do have different parametrizations, that's why I use different $\lambda$ subscripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: For this particular surface you are considering, the relation is true.

From page-19 of Visual Differential Geometry by Tristan Needham

> [image]

You can pretty easily see that the geodesic circle of radius $r$ centered at the point $c$, has the same linear relation of $s = r \theta$ going on i.e: sectors of equal angle are have same arclength.

Comment: Hmm, but my question is why can't I just find the angle using the tangent vectors $d \mathbf{x} / d \lambda_1$ and $d \mathbf{x} / d \lambda_2$ and their dot product using the metric?

Comment: Ok, I just checked again... it seems the euclidean relation holds exactly in spherical case. I'll upload a picture in a bit @BrainStrokePatient

Comment: @BrainStrokePatient Please see the edited answer, does it make sense now?